# How to detect if a link takes you to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Let's say I have a function called `linksToAnotherPage` that receives an href. How can I check if the href takes you to another page or if it is a
`tel:` , `mailto:`,  `#anchor-link`, etc that does not take you to another page?

```
function linksToAnotherPage(href) {
 ....
}

linksToAnotherPage('tel:123-456-7890') -> // false
linksToAnotherPage('contact') -> // true
```

--

```
// does not link to another page

<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
<a href="mailto:email@example.com">Send Email</a>
<a href="#start-now">Start Now</a>

// links to another page
<a href="contact">Send Email</a>
```

--

UPDATE: here is my current solution based on the answers received

```
    function isInteractiveHref (href) {
        return (
            href.startsWith("mailto:") || href.startsWith("tel:") || 
            href.startsWith("#")
        )        
    }

    isInteractiveHref(props.href) ? (
        <Link href={props.href}>
            <a>Does not link to another page</a>
        </Link>
    ) : <Link href={'/' + props.href}>
            <a> Links to another page</a>
        </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple if statement for that, there are limited type of links which will go to another page:

- links which starts with "/"
- links which starts with "http://", "https://", or "wwww."

So, I think this function can help:

```
function linksToAnotherPage(href) {
   if (href.startsWith("/") || href.startsWith("http://" || href.startsWith("https://" || href.startsWith("www."){
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: Currently, none of my links start with a "/". I have a button component that takes a link. It takes links of all kinds from `tel:` to links like `contact` which takes you to another page. For links that take you to another page,  it does not have a starting backslash. It is always `contact` not `/contact`. I am trying to figure the problem in my OP  so I can make my button component  add the `/` to links that take you to another page.

Comment: Also, you can have an if statement for the other part, the ones that they Don't go to another page. It seems they are limited too. (?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function linksToAnotherPage(href) {
  if(['tel','mailto'].some(i=>href.startsWith(`${i}:`))) return false;
  let a = new URL(window.location.href);
  let b = new URL(href, window.location.href);
  return !['protocol', 'host', 'pathname', 'search']
    .every(i=>a[i]===b[i]);
}
```

You can find a list of URL prefixes you may want to additionally match here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes